# How to bring a docker data container to Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have an application that relies on 4 docker data containers for the data it needs to run some tests. At the moment I have their docker-compose file and their images but I don't have access to the data containers Dockerfile or actual data.

How this application works in docker-compose is as below:
The application is called `rtsp_server` and it loads different volumes from the data containers such as `st-andries4`(I just wrote one of them).

This is their docker-compose:

```
# The application
rtsp_server:
  image: rtsp_server_image
  volumes_from:
    - rtsp_data_st_andries4:ro
  ports:
    - "8554:8554"
  command: python ./rtsp-server.py /rtsp_data/st-andries-4 st_andries_4

# Data container
rtsp_data_st_andries4:
  image: st_andries_4:1
  volumes:
    - /rtsp_data/st-andries-4
  command: /bin/true
  mem_limit: 10000000000
```

I already brought the application, `rtsp_server`, to Kubernetes and it works fine but I need to also bring the data containers to k8s but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure if you want to create a Persistent Volume on Kubernetes or move date from existing Docker data containers.

Here is a Kubernetes documentation on how to [Configure a Pod to Use a PersistentVolume for Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/).

First you should create a [`PersistentVolume`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

Then [`PersistentVolumeClaim`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolumeclaim) because this is was `pod` uses to request physical storage.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

And finally you can add a `volumeMounts` inside your pod that might look like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

**Update**

To share PVC between many pods you would have to set up:

```
spec:
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
```

I would also recommend checking this blog [Create ReadWriteMany PersistentVolumeClaims on your Kubernetes Cluster](https://medium.com/asl19-developers/create-readwritemany-persistentvolumeclaims-on-your-kubernetes-cluster-3a8db51f98e3) and choosing which solution fits your needs.

You might be also interested in project [Rook](https://rook.io/docs/rook/v1.1/) which is Open-Source, Cloud-Native Storage for Kubernetes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about PV and PVC but I am not sure if this works since a PV must be shared between at least 2 pods, the data container and the application and these 2 can be running on different nodes. I think one way is I use an NFS server so 2 pods can share a PV but is there any way that I do it without an NFS server?

Comment: @AVarf, I've updated the answer. I hope this will be more useful.